# How to add 'Read more' in the author's long biography in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How to add 'Read more' in the author's long biography in WordPress. After clicking on 'Read More', read the author directly on the author's profile page.Please try to solve the problem.
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see **more** button as shown in below screenshot. Decide your break point where you want to put read more button, put the cursor there and click on the more button. But when you click on the more button there will not be any text for the read more button. To edit read more button put the below function in your functions.php file.

[image]

Adding this code to your functions.php file enables you to customize the read more link text.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

Reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: hello sir, but i want to this for author bio box.